# What traits would plants have if no animals or humans existed?

Tags: evolution, flora, alternate-reality

On a planet very similar to earth, but absent insects and animals, what general traits would plants have?

Not looking for specific varieties, but more for general traits, like

- would plants be larger or smaller
- taller or wider
- methods of reproduction
- seed dispersal
- Bacteria still exists.
- Would there still be oases in the deserts? If yes, then how would they be different?

Comment: What does flourish imply that's different than how life proceeded on earth for millions/billions of years before humans started having big impacts on the environment? Also, do mean plants as they are now (such as if animals and humans vanished over night)? Or how plants might have evolved starting from a point before animals had ever existed?

Comment: What I mean by flourish is survive or be larger or healthier if no animals interacted with it. And no animals means that animals never evolved on this planet.

Comment: This is far too big of a change to the history of life to predict well.

Comment: Imagine a planet where animals and humans don't exist. But everything that isn't affected by humans and animals is the same as the real world. Are the plants larger or smaller? Does this help?

Comment: There is some risk that in the absence of any animals, phytoplankton would rule the oceans, precluding development of higher plants.

Comment: *"But everything that isn't affected by humans and animals is the same as the real world":* This is not how natural evolution works. *Everything is connected,* because everything lives in the same ecosystem. The question does not state what counts as a "plant" or an "animal"; let's say that by "plants" you mean the land plants, [Embryophyta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embryophyte), and by animals you mean the [Metazoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal). Now, the Metazoa appeared a long long time before the Embryophyta; nobody can tell how life would have evolved in this alternate world.

Comment: well there would be no flowering or fruiting plants to start. which basically means no angiosperms.

Comment: Take a look at the [Devonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devonian) and [Carboniferous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carboniferous) eras for a fair idea of plant life ruling the land with minimal interference from pesky animal

Comment: Hello Anderson, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. You're asking what we call a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609) and they're off-topic. It's purely opinion-based as to what plants would exist, flourish, or change. VTC:Needs-Focus

Comment: @JBH Disagree to VTC. It may be high concept but asking, "which varieties of plants would exist?" and "What traits would plants have in this scenario?" are two different questions.

Comment: @ITAlex Two different questions is VTC:Needs-Focus (one-specific-question/one-best-answer). And I frankly believe it's impossible to meaningfully know what plants would exist and what their traits would be. That's just guessing (VTC:Opinion-Based).

Comment: @JBH ...really? Not every question is going to be hard science. This one in particular is soft science. Not all answers here are created equal. If I said that "all plants would no longer have roots" I would be inherently wrong. If I tried to inject magic into this question I would also be wrong.

Comment: @ITAlex Is there an argument here? This question cannot be objectively answered and it's impossible to objectively pick a best answer. The [help/dont-ask] states that questions shouldn't be asked where every answer is equally valid. It's impossible to determine the difference between "they'd change radically" and "they wouldn't change at all." The whole point of Stack Exchange is that questions shouldn't be answered with guesses - and that's all any answer to this question (or any question about "how would X evolve?") can be.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your concern. But this is for a science FICTION story. I can just make the best guess I can make with my limited knowledge of science.

Comment: @Anderson I would suggest that you do more research. Perhaps in the biology stackexchange.

Comment: Okay. thank you.

Comment: Personally I think this is a great worldbuilding question! Gets right to the heart of the nature of the world in question. I don't think this particular question (or even this kind of question) needs to be read too broadly or too scientifically. A little deentomological imagineering is really that's needed here! VTR.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to presume that there is still bacteria. You need something to break down dead plants and release carbon. Otherwise all the carbon gets locked into the forest floor and plant growth dies for lack of carbon.

**Pollinating Plants**

There could still be pollinating plants. They would just depend on [wind](https://ucanr.edu/sites/PollenNation/Meet_The_Pollinators/Wind/#:%7E:text=Wind%20pollinating%20plants%20release%20billions,crop%20plants%20are%20wind%2Dpollinated) instead of animals to transport their pollen.  Many species of nut trees are already pollinated via wind. They will tend to release a huge number of very small pollen grains, small enough to float around as a dust mote. If there *were* animals around, the animals would all be sneezing.

**Flowering Plants**

They would not have huge attractive flowers because they would not be attempting to attract bees etc.  Instead they would have structures to release pollen and other structures to catch it. It might mean that the catching structures were sticky, at least sticky for pollen. Possibly the catching structures might have elaboration to add surface area, or funnel wind to a central structure. A tree might arrange its branches to act as a pollen funnel and filter. But they would be unlikely to be elaborately colored.

**Hitchhiking Plants**

Hitchhiking seeds would be missing. Burrs and such. A couple weeks ago I was exploring in the woods and I barely nudged this shrub. It dumped a huge quantity of small seeds in my hair that I needed hours to comb out. Each seed had a little hook on it that only came out of my hair with difficulty. Possibly I left a long comet-trail of seeds that will sprout in the spring. This would not develop without animals.

**Fruits and Nuts**

They won't produce fruit as enticement to animals to carry their seeds around. Nor would they produce nectar such as bees collect. And they would not produce a scent to attract nor repel animals. The forest smells might be dominated by the smell of bacteria breaking down dead plant matter.

They might produce a different kind of thing to place nutrients ready for the seed. Or to help with seed transport. Coconuts might be an example. And various things like the fluff on a dandelion seed. Or a tumbleweed. And of course various nuts and seeds that provide nutrients for the embryonic plant.

Indeed, with animals not around to eat the seeds, they might invest more energy in providing their seedlings with energy to get started. So there might be much larger species of nuts. And, again without animals, the shells on the nuts might be much thinner or even absent. The structure of a nut would be there to provide mechanical support rather than protect against something eating it. Or it might be there with a built in means of breaking open only under conditions that the seedling will survive. Say when the coconut gets tossed onto an island and dries out, or gets the salt washed out by rain, etc.

Grass and certain types of trees would be the example.  Think about the tassel on the top of a corn plant, and the silk on the end of an ear of corn. The tassel releases pollen, the silk catches it.

**Pollination**

In some species there is a mechanism to keep the pollen from pollinating the same plant. Some species that pollinate this way have a male plant and a female plant, for example. There are other mechanisms. So it would require groups of plants not too far apart. You would get a grove of wind-pollinating tree. There would be competing forces between transporting seeds to new fertile ground and keeping close enough to readily find a pollen partner.

**Plant Defenses**

Species with defenses against animals would be missing. Thorns for example. The prickles on thistles. The sting in a stinging nettle. The poison in nightshade. And species like poison ivy or poison oak. Though some species might accidentally have a poisonous chemical because it was useful in their metabolism, it would be unlikely to be as strong or as common as it is now. Indeed, many plants have some degree of defense against being eaten. This includes such trivial things as bitter taste. But it also includes such things as a species of tree in New Zealand that was adapted to an animal that wanted to eat its leaves. Adult trees do not have any branches low enough for this animal to get at them. That animal species has died out, probably because of invading humans rather than because the tree managed to starve them.  The tree remains with this minimum branch height.

Comment: Thank you! This was very useful.

Answer (score 3):

General traits are difficult to define - plants that use the wind to pollinate and/or disperse their seeds vary in form from grasses to very large trees.

And it is wrong to assume that all plants would stop flowering - some flowering plants -  including members of the orchid, pea family (legumes), sunflower and some daisy-type plants tend to self-pollinate.

Also there are many flowering plants that reproduce mostly vegetatively. There are many different ways they do this: stem runners (like spider plants, brambles and strawberries), root suckers (Bananas, many fruit trees), bulbs (Daffodils, Tulips Onions), tubers (Potatoes, Yams) corms (iris and gladioli) and plantlets/bulbils (Mexican Hat Plant, Agave).

So don't assume your Earth-like planet would be flowerless.

Comment: Thank you! This was very useful.